# What kind of motherboard would be good for my PC? How much does it cost?

Tags: motherboard, desktop, low-cost

So, I am working on opening a computer company (called Opportunity Computing in case you were wondering) and my first concept, the ME mark 1, requires a motherboard that can handle the heavy-duty jobs that ME mk1 is designed to do. It needs to have enough computing power to be used professionally but not so much that it would be (too) expensive. I *Emphasize* that my budget isn't really in great shape right now due to reasons I'd rather not mention.

Comment: "requires a motherboard that can handle the heavy-duty jobs that ME mk1 is designed to do" - What does this mean? What is it designed to do? What are your requirements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this one. I don't know if it is compatible with windows 11 though.

I would recommend trying to update to windows 11. Though I do warn that this is only a 1rst generation ASUS motherboard. I hope ME mk1 goes down well with those who buy it!
buy the motherboard [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KH12V25)

Comment: The question doesn't say what they need at all. I wouldn't recommend something without knowing any requirements at all. It is more than likely the wrong choice. You just assumed OP wants Windows 11 and an AMD CPU?

Comment: @Romen I really don't care what OS it has. I just want it to be durable and oporational.

Comment: @OpportunityComputing You did not tell us what you want at all in the original question. Do not tell us in the comment under an answer, edit the question instead. I see you already selected the answer though so that must mean you're happy with the first and only suggestion you've seen.